# i have a stackoverflow i think(SDL surface limit reached)

Tags: c++, sdl, stack-overflow

so im using sdl, and im trying to make a sprite sheet of 360 different rotations, using SDL_GetError: "Width or height is too large"
for my sprite sheet where each individual image is 63x63 pixels, the dimensions that i want is 
width = 63x360
hight = 63

what is a right approach for this problem? should i not use the sprite sheet technique? or somehow i can increase the maximum memory usage of surfaces?

```
SDL_Surface * p = SDL_CreateRGBSurface(SDL_SWSURFACE,newWidth*MODERATION,newHeight,BPP,0xFF0000,0xFF00,0xFF,0xFF000000);
std::cout<< SDL_GetError() << '\n';
```

Answer (score 0):

Organize the sprites in a 2D array like `36 x 10`.  The indexing will be a little more complicated, but you'll get the width way down.  Notice that it's complaining about "Width or height" and not the total memory usage.